# Threejs and wp integration

Tags: wordpress, threejs-editor

I want to use threejs with wordpress cany anybody tell a step by step way to do so?

I got a way to include js in wordpress but unable to import threejs error showing cannot use import outside module

Answer (score 0):

It is great mistake you did with code placement.

You are trying to use ES Module features or syntax in es5.
So, it's throw error

```
Cannot use 'import or export' like syntax outside Module.
```

If you code has import and export like syntax it must be ES Module.

So add type=module attribute to script

```
<script type="module" src="./file/url.js"></script>
```